# How to update WPF image.Source on value change in separate static class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, camera

I recently switched from Forms to WPF to gain some new expertise. 
To start I thought of programming a camera application.
The camera is accessed in its own static class (as I only have one camera - so multiple instances are not necessary).
The UI is supposed to show the current image in a Live view via an image control. The camera class updates a BitmapSource in an infinite loop, that I then want to use as the Source for my image control.

I just don't know how to make it so that the change of the bitmapSource causes the update of the image control. How is that typically done? I read about Propertychangedevents but have no idea how to implement them in this scenario.
In my previous Forms application I had a timer that updated the form 30 times per second and used the public bitmap as source for a picturebox control. But that is an ugly way and I want to do it better.

The code looks like:
Camera class

```
static class CameraClass
{
    static Camera myCam = new Camera(); //from API
    public static BitmapSource CurrentCameraImage;

    private static void GetCameraImages()
    {
       while(true)
       {
           myCam.GetImage(out CurrentCameraImage, 1000); //from API
       }
    }

    public static void StartCamera()
    {
        myCam.StartAcquisition(); //from API
        Task.Run(() => { GetCameraImages(); });
    }
}
```

standard WPF class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CameraClass.StartCamera(); 
        //this should now cause the image control to update 
        //everytime the bitmapsource is changed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WPF applications usually implement the MVVM pattern, where view elements are bound to properties in the view model. In the most simple case there is just an instance of a view model class that is assigned to the `DataContext` property of the applications's MainWindow.

Your view model class could look like this:

```
class CameraViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Camera camera = new Camera();
    private BitmapSource currentCameraImage;

    public BitmapSource CurrentCameraImage
    {
        get { return currentCameraImage; }
        set
        {
            currentCameraImage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentCameraImage"));
        }
    }

    public async Task StartCamera()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                BitmapSource bitmap;
                camera.GetImage(out bitmap, 1000); // from API

                bitmap.Freeze(); // make bitmap cross-thread accessible
                CurrentCameraImage = bitmap;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow constructor you would create an instance of the view model and assign it to the `DataContext` property like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new CameraViewModel();
    viewModel.StartCamera();

    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Finally, there would be an Image element in XAML that is bound to the view model's `CurrentCameraImage` property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentCameraImage}"/>
```

---

In an improved implementation of the view model, the Task should probably be awaited in an async method.

Comment: but that is not actually an answer as to how to do this with a static class no?

Comment: No, but it shows how you should really do it. On StackOverflow, answers often go beyond the details of a question, in order to show the asker (and other people that come along) how problems are generally solved.

Comment: the question was pretty specific as to how to do this with a static class since the general solution does not work. Your answer is just a rewrite of the documentation and does not answer the actual question. I am thankful for the response however can not officially accept it since it does not solve the issue. In my project I left out the static class now - but only because I could not find any other way and not because I wanted to :(

Answer (score 0):

As you said you wanted to learn about WPF, you won't do anything wrong by looking at `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you search samples even here on stack overflow, that'll give you a gentle introduction.

With that you would usually data bind your XAML Image to the image source with something similar to

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentCameraImage}" />
```

The code above is just an indication, I'm not at a computer right now.

To avoid the static class you could turn `CameraClass` into a `Singleton`.

Does that make sense? If the data-binding approach is not what you are up to (e.g. you need to learn what a BindingContext is), then have a look at how to include `event`s: Your camera class would define an event and your main class will subscribe to it. That event will then signal your main class that an update is available and lets you update the picture on your UI from the camera.

Comment: trying INotifyPropertyChanged was the first thing I di. But applying it to the static class gives me an error saying that "static classes can not implement interfaces".

Comment: Ok, maybe you can go for the singleton in that case.